# Is there a way to use IAM policies to restrict the creation of S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags, amazon-iam

I want to restrict bucket creation such that users can only create buckets if they have included the following tags: business_unit, product, and component. Is there a way to do this using IAM policies, specifically IAM request tag policy?

I know that this can be done with EC2s, so I was wondering if the same is applicable to S3 buckets, because I can't find any documentation on it. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

Similar to [Deny CreateBucket in S3 unless AES256 Encryption Checked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57173868/174777), the `CreateBucket()` command does not allow tags to be specified.

Instead, tags are added *after bucket creation* by using the `PutBucketTagging()` command.

It works when launching Amazon EC2 instances because the `RunIntances()` command accepts tags. Permission to use the command can therefore be restricted based upon the presence of those tags.